# Call to a member function prepare() on null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent, closures

I'm trying to add a where condition using a function but this causes me to get the following error:

```
Call to a member function prepare() on null in /vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php line 327
```

```
public function getAllTeams()
{
    $query = Team::where('tstatus', '!=', 'Deleted')
                ->where('tstatus', '!=', 'Ended');

    var_dump($query->getQuery()->connection->getPdo());
    $query->where(function($a){
            $a->where('tname', '=', "John's Team")
            ->orWhere('tname', '=', "Mark's Team");
    });
    var_dump($query->getQuery()->connection->getPdo());

    return $query->get();
}
```

If I remove the where tname part the query runs perfectly fine.

The var_dumps output the following

```
<small>Repositories/TeamRepository.php:31:</small><b>object</b(<i>Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection</i>)[<i>590</i>]</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>Repositories/TeamRepository.php:36:</small><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
```

I've done some digging into the Laravel code and it's this part in the following code that causes the $pdo variable to be set to null

```
$this->model->newModelQuery()
```

```
/**
 * Add a basic where clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  \Closure|string|array  $column
 * @param  mixed   $operator
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @return $this
 */
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    if ($column instanceof Closure) {
        $column($query = $this->model->newModelQuery());
        $this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);
    } else {
        $this->query->where(...func_get_args());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I edited Builder.php and made it work with the following code but obviously editing an existing library isn't the solution.

Why would the $pdo variable be set to null when I use a Closure but work fine when I don't?

Comment: Where is the part of the code containing `prepare()`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense that's the second part of his code `
    $query->where(function($a){
            $a->where('tname', '=', "John's Team")
            ->orWhere('tname', '=', "Mark's Team");
    });`

Comment: the second part of the code $param->where isn't set to a variable where you're doing $query->get();
maybe change it to `$query = $query->where(function($a....` ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ $query->get() makes the DB call so prepare() is called as part of that.

Comment: @Emad I tried that to no avail. I also tried putting in a return statement before $a->where( but that didn't make any difference either

Comment: Your best bet would be dd($query->toSql());, you will get a clear view of what's happening in your query, with or without the closure

Comment: It would be funny but it might be the single quote in the search term `John's`.. try to remove it to see if the error still appears

Comment: i can see that your issue isn't really in the query, php version? laravel version? any modified file previously ?, maybe remove the laravel from vendor then do a composer install? my Builder's where method looks a bit different than yours with `$column($query = $this->model->newQueryWithoutRelationships());` instead of `$column($query = $this->model->newModelQuery());`